# Closed Subsets of Compact Spaces Using Subsequences Definition of Compactness

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove closed subsets of compact spaces are compact.

I've seen the proof with the open cover definition of compactness, so I would like to prove this using the subsequence definition of compactness (in metric spaces). In case anyone is not familiar with this definition: For all $\{ x_n\}\subset X$, if there is a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}\subset X\implies \text{ (sequential) compactness, where }X$ is a metric space.

My attempt:

Let $K$ be a compact metric space. This implies that $K$ is both closed and bounded. Let $K_0\subset K$ be closed. This means all limit points of $K_0$ are contained in $K_0$. Suppose that $\{x_n\}\subset K_0$. Then $\{x_{n_k}\}$ has a limit in $K$ since $K$ is compact.

I am stuck at this point. I want to show that the limit of the subsequence converges to a limit in $K_0$. If I could do this, then it would meet the definition of compactness using subsequences.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that $(x_n)$ is also in $K_0$, and since it it closed, its limit point must also live in $K_0$

Comment: "This means all limit points of $K_0$ are contained in $K_0$". And since the limit of the subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is a limit point of $K_0$ or a point occurring infinitely often in the sequence, it belongs to $K_0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: How do I know that the limit of the subsequence is in $K_0$? $K$ is closed as well, so isn't it possible that the limit is in $K$ but not in $K_0$?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan, no you started with the sequence in $K_0$, it is closed, so its limit point must also be in $K_0$.

Comment: If the limit is a point of the sequence, it is clear that it belongs to $K_0$, since all points of the sequence are in $K_0$. If the limit is not a point of the sequence, it is a limit point of the set $S = \{ x_{n_k} : k\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and therefore it is also a limit point of all sets containing $S$. But $S\subset K_0$, hence it is a limit point of $K_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is the limit then for every $\varepsilon>0$ we have $\left|x-x_{n_{k}}\right|<\varepsilon$ for
$k$ large enough, so $N_{\varepsilon}\left(x\right)\cap K_{0}\ne\emptyset$
where $N_{\varepsilon}\left(x\right):=\left\{ y\mid\left|x-y\right|<\varepsilon\right\} $.
That is characteristic for elements $x$ belonging to $\overline{K}_{0}$.

Since $K_0$ is closed we have $\overline{K}_{0}=K_0$